# Giving a session-local temporary name to a schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgresql-8.4

I have a schema `foo_bar` but also `foo_x`. During a particular session, is it possible to just set `foo_bar` to `bar` in PostgreSQL (8.4)?

Comment: Do you mean `alter schema foo_bar rename to bar`?

Comment: will that work only for the session ? or will it be permanent?

Comment: Lack of punctuation makes it somewhat difficult to understand what your question is exactly. Are you asking *whether you can* rename a schema so that it affects only the current session? Is that the issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: yes. sorry about the lack of punctiation

Comment: Please note that `psql` is a client application to PostgreSQL (or Postgres for short).  Also, 8.4 is very old, now out of support for years.  Please consider upgrading to something newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. If you check the [documentation on `ALTER SCHEMA` (PostgreSQL 8.4)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-alterschema.html), there is not such a thing as `ALTER SCHEMA TEMPORARILY` or anything similar.

What you could actually do (per session), is change your [`search_path` setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-client.html). Citing the documentation:

> `search_path (string)`
>
> This variable specifies the order in which schemas are searched when an object (table, data type, function, etc.) is referenced by a simple name with **no schema component**. When there are objects of identical names in different schemas, the one found first in the search path is used. An object that is not in any of the schemas in the search path can only be referenced by specifying its containing schema with a qualified (dotted) name.

Depending on your specific use-case (the need for a temporary change of schema name wasn't mentioned), this *might* be helpful.

Comment: This is the best idea, all he has to do is remove the schema qualification from everything or preproccess them and add it back with a macro.